# How many codes written by perl in debian?

Tags: debian, perl

My debian os:

```
cat   /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
```

There is the code to calculate codes written by perl in Debian woody,
[calculate code in os](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-manual/ch03s06.en.html#id-1.4.7.9)

For example, in Debian woody it is around 400-500 Mbs, try this:

```
size=0
for i in `grep -A 1 -B 1 "^Section: base" /var/lib/dpkg/available | grep -A 2 "^Priority: required" |grep "^Installed-Size" |cut -d : -f 2
`; do size=$(($size+$i)); done
echo $size
 47762
```

I copy all codes and execute in my os :

```
debian@debian:~$ size=0
debian@debian:~$ for i in `grep -A 1 -B 1 "^Section: base" /var/lib/dpkg/available |
  grep -A 2 "^Priority: required" |grep "^Installed-Size" |cut -d : -f 2
  `; do size=$(($size+$i)); done
debian@debian:~$ echo $size
0
```

Why the size is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### wrong code

If I follow your link, the code is:

```
for i in /bin/* /sbin/* /usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/*; do
    [ -f $i ] && {
        type=`file $i | grep -il perl`
        [ -n "$type" ] && echo $i;
    }
done
```

Moreover, in your attempt (see upper), you are trying to `grep` the `base` section from the file, and like on my debian, this section isn't present there, so zero result is normal.

### Solution

```
#!/bin/bash

size=0
for i in /bin/* /sbin/* /usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/*; do
    [[ -x $i ]] &&
    file -i $i |
    grep -q perl &&
    ds=$(du $i | awk '{print $1}')
    ((size+=ds))
done
echo "$((size/1024)) MiB"
```